# java code to connect weblogic datasource to particular target

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, datasource

I have requirement in which i need to connect to datasource each individual target.
If datsource has two target then i need to connect to both target one by one.

I am using below code for datasource connection.
Need to know how to connect to individual target of datasource

```
public class ConnectWLSDataSource  {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Connection conn;
 Statement stmt;
 ResultSet rs;
 String str1;

try {
 Properties prop = new Properties();

prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, “weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory”);
 prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, “t3://HOST_NAME:PORT_NUMBER”);
 Context ctx = new InitialContext(prop);
 Object obj = ctx.lookup(“DATA_SOURCE_NAME”); // java:comp/env/CPDS
 System.out.println(“Data Source Found….”);

DataSource ds = (DataSource) obj;
 conn = ds.getConnection();
 System.out.println(“Data Source User Name::”+conn.getMetaData().getUserName());
 stmt = conn.createStatement();

String query = “select 1 from dual”;
 System.out.println(“Query ” + query);
 rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
 if (rs != null) {
 System.out.println(“Some Data Found in Query”);
 } else {
 System.out.println(“No Data Found in Query”);
 }
 ctx.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }

}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change the `PROVIDER_URL` to the specific host you want. For instance we have 4 servers running in a cluster and can choose to use a load balancer if we want to round-robin the connections or we can pick one specific server in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

we face issue when using this code, and get below exception. in all if 100 requests are serviced one fails with the below exception.

javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3://prod.abc.com:7114: Destination unreachable; nested exception is:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; No available router to destination].